# ASP.NET MVC3: Alternatives to using ValidateInput

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3

We are working on an ASP.NET MVC3 project that utilizes lots of html forms.

Because of ValidateInput=true, < and > characters are forbidden through the site (except html enabled fields (AllowHtml)).

But instead of having server throw "A potentially dangerous Request.Form value was detected from the client" error, we want to catch the error and return an error in modelstate, highlighting the field and saying "You can not use < and > characters".

Is there an easy way to do this or do we have to turn validateinput to false and manually (or by a custom filter) check and implement this for each post function?

Comment: Why not use a `RegexAttribute`? If you have unobstrusive (client side) validation enabled then this should be enough. If you need to validate on the server then I would use a combination of the `AllowHtmlAttribute` and a `RegexAttribute`

Comment: Nice. I'll try this thanks. (This still means that i need to manually put regexattribute to all text fields, right?)

Comment: @Yes you would. Either that or implement `IValidateableObject` and validate all your text fields on the model at once. However, you'll not get the automatic client side validation with this method.